# Encoding/import Adwords .CSV into powerquery

Tags: unicode, encoding, google-ads-api, powerquery, m

Basics: of the question: how are .cvs reports from Google Adwords encoded?

Details: I'm trying to import a .csv from adwords using powerquery and for the life of me I can't get the "," (comma) characters to appear in my import.

My Code:

```
let
// Get raw file data as txt file,
fnRawFileContents = (fullpath) as table =>
let
    EveryLine = Lines.FromBinary(File.Contents(fullpath),1,true,1200),
    Value = Table.FromList((EveryLine),Splitter.SplitByNothing())
in
    Value,

// Use functions to load contents
   Source =  fnRawFileContents("C:\Users\Jamie.Marshall\Desktop\Emma\adwordsDoc.csv"),
    #"Removed Top Rows" = Table.Skip(Source,1)
in
    #"Removed Top Rows"
```

Facts:

1. Adwords documentation says they use UTC-16LE
2. UTC-16LE in M is code page 1200
3. I cannot open the Adwords .csv in notepad under any encoding setting (Unicode, Unicode Big Endian, UTF-8, ASNI)
4. If resave the file in excel as UnicodeText I can open it with notepad as Unicode Big Endian with linebreaks, but no commas (",").

---

- How can I verify the encoding on these docs?
- What other encoding could this be?
- Any help on this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why you use lines instead of native csv-parser?

Use `Csv.Document(file_content, [Delimiter="#(tab)", Columns=10, Encoding=1200, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])`

Like this

```
let
    file_path = "C:\Users\Jamie.Marshall\Desktop\Emma\adwordsDoc.csv",
    file_content = File.Contents(file_path),
    csv = Csv.Document(file_content, [Delimiter="#(tab)", Columns=10, Encoding=1200, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    skip_1_row = Table.Skip(csv,1),
    promote_header = Table.PromoteHeaders(skip_1_row),
    remove_last_2_rows = Table.RemoveLastN(promote_header,2)
in
    remove_last_2_rows
```